# c# Wpf application crashes on W10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I've been struggling with this issue, for 2 days 
I Made a WPF application with W7. the application works fine with W7 but when i want to run it with W10.
It works in the beggining but when i want to open a window it crashes 
i tried to debug with some MessageBox in  my code behind but when it calls a mutliValueconverter and crashes 
i went to see in the events log and got an error with KernelBase.dll 
Here is my MultiValueConverter Class 
and the screenshot of the error in the event log 
          [!Text][event log 1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnrnq.png)

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Globalization;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Windows;
        using System.Windows.Controls;
        using System.Windows.Data;
        using System.Windows.Media;

        namespace EasyMaintenance
        {
               public class HighlighterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
                {
                    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                    CultureInfo culture)
           {           
            if (values[1] is DataRow)
            {
                var cell = (DataGridCell)values[0];
                var row = (DataRow)values[1];
                var columnName = cell.Column.SortMemberPath;
                //MessageBox.Show(cell.ToString());
                //

                foreach (arcad arcad in Fichess.arcad_list)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (arcad.couleur == "rouge" && row[columnName].ToString() == arcad.lib && arcad.couleur2 == "vert")
                        {
                           // MessageBox.Show("Coloration en Rouge");
                            return Brushes.Red;
                        }

                        if (arcad.couleur2 == "vert" && row[columnName].ToString() == arcad.lib)
                        {
                           // MessageBox.Show("Coloration en Vert");
                            return Brushes.Green;
                        }
                        if (arcad.couleur2 == "Blue" && row[columnName].ToString() == arcad.lib)
                        {
                           // MessageBox.Show("Coloration en bleu");
                            return Brushes.Blue;
                        }

                    }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                              MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                        }

                    if (arcad.couleur2 == "blanche" && row[columnName].ToString() == arcad.lib)
                    {
                   // MessageBox.Show("Coloration en chocolat");
                    return Brushes.Chocolate;
                    }

                }
            }
            return SystemColors.AppWorkspaceColor;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

}

and here is the eventlog error of .NET RunTime

[eventlog2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km0Jr.png)
[eventlog3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzK8F.png)

EDIT : 
My screen of the stacktrace was incomplete here is the Full stack trace in XML format 
 Can somebody reedit that it doesnt work for me

> Application : EasyMaintenance.exe Version du Framework :
>   v4.0.30319            Description : le processus a été arrêté en
>   raison d'une exception non gérée.   Informations sur l'exception :
>   System.InvalidOperationException à System.Windows.TriggerBase.Seal() à
>   System.Windows.Trigger.Seal() à
>   System.Windows.TriggerCollection.Seal() à System.Windows.Style.Seal()
>   à
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(System.Windows.FrameworkElement,
>   System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement, System.Windows.Style,
>   System.Windows.Style, System.Windows.Style ByRef) à
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) à
>   System.Windows.PropertyChangedCallback.Invoke(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) à
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   à
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   à
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   à
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex,
>   System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata,
>   System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType) à
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.CoerceValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
>   à
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridHelper.TransferProperty(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.DependencyProperty) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnColumnChanged(System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn,
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnColumnChanged(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) à
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   à
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   à
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   à
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex,
>   System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata,
>   System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType) à
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty,
>   System.Object, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, Boolean, Boolean,
>   System.Windows.OperationType, Boolean) à
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyKey,
>   System.Object) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.PrepareCell(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow, Int32) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Object) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.PrepareItemContainer(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Object) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.PrepareItemContainer(System.Windows.DependencyObject)
>   à System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.InsertContainer(Int32,
>   System.Windows.UIElement, Boolean) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.AddContainerFromGenerator(Int32,
>   System.Windows.UIElement, Boolean) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.GenerateChild(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator,
>   System.Windows.Size, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn, Int32
>   ByRef, System.Windows.Size ByRef) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.DetermineRealizedColumnsBlockList(System.Windows.Size)
>   à
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
>   à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size) à
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(System.Windows.UIElement,
>   System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
>   à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
>   à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32, Boolean) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator
>   ByRef, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IContainItemStorage ByRef,
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IContainItemStorage ByRef,
>   System.Object ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Double ByRef, Double ByRef,
>   Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef, System.Collections.IList ByRef,
>   System.Object ByRef, System.Collections.IList ByRef, Int32 ByRef,
>   Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef, System.Windows.Size ByRef,
>   System.Windows.Rect ByRef,
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizationCacheLength ByRef,
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit ByRef, Boolean
>   ByRef, Double ByRef, System.Windows.Size ByRef, System.Windows.Size
>   ByRef, System.Windows.Size ByRef, System.Windows.Size ByRef,
>   System.Windows.Size ByRef, System.Windows.Size ByRef,
>   System.Windows.Size ByRef, System.Windows.Size ByRef, Boolean ByRef,
>   Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, Boolean
>   ByRef) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(System.Windows.Size,
>   System.Nullable`1<Double> ByRef,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ByRef,
>   System.Nullable`1 ByRef, Boolean) à
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
>   à
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
>   à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size) à
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout() à
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(System.Object)
>   à System.Windows.Media.MediaContext+InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork() à
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks() à
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object)
>   à
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(System.Object)
>   à
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget)
>   à System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize() à
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage,
>   IntPtr, IntPtr) à
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) à
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean
>   ByRef) à
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) à
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32) à
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) à
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) à
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr)

and here is the Xaml of which it crashes when it tries to read it

```
<DataGrid x:Name="arcad_Grid"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="499" Margin="12,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Loaded="getArcadVersion" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow"  SelectionChanged="Arcad_Grid_SelectionChanged" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem="dataGrid1_CleanUpVirtualizedItem" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource          myHighlighterConverter}" >
                                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"></Binding>
                                    <Binding Path="Row"></Binding>
                                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Chocolate" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="Chocolate" >
                            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Chocolate" />
                        </Trigger>


                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Chocolate"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: The stacktrace from the first screenshot seems incomplete. Can you post the entire thing?

Comment: Please have a look on "Fix 2" & "Fix 3" from the link https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fix-kernelbase-dll-crash-issue/

Comment: Can you confirm that Win10 machine has correct .NET version installed, i.e. the same as Win7.

Comment: yes the W10 has the .NET 4.8 and the W7 has 4.8 also

Comment: The part of the stack trace in eventlog2 seems to point to an issue with a Trigger within a Style. From the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/TriggerBase.cs,6953a4edfef529ea) probably a trigger cycle.

Comment: i updated the full stack trace and Added the Xaml of which i think it's where it crashed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this trigger supposed to do?

```
<Trigger Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="Chocolate" >
    <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Chocolate" />
</Trigger>
```

It seems as if you're trying to set the `DataGridCell`'s background to `Chocolate` whenever its background is `Chocolate`?

You would end up with infinite recursion as whenever you change the background to `Chocolate`, the trigger fires and changes the background to `Chocolate`, firing the trigger which changes the background to `Chocolate`, and so on.

Comment: i came to the same conclusion as well. i used that trigger at runtime of the datagrid to keep the backrgound's color of the cell at chocolate but i realize i did the samething in my code behind. Thanks for your help